# Dynamically added DIV with both dragging and resizing capabilities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var total = 0;

function add() 
{
    total++;
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + '<div id="'+total+'" class="drag"></div>';
    $('.drag').draggable().resizable();
}

add();
add();
add();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zVZFq/631/

The script I revised works (sorta) but the problem is that the last div with the class `.drag` that is dynamically added to the `body` element using the javascript function `add()` **replaces** the `sizable()` functionality of the other divs with the class `.drag` but **not** for some reason, their `draggabble()` functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works:

```
var t = 0;

function add() {

    $('body').append('<div id="d'+t+'" class="drag"></div>');
    $('#d'+t).draggable().resizable();
    t++;
}
```

here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zVZFq/634/

Answer (score 1):

This might make it work:

```
function add() {
       total++;
       var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
       myDiv.setAttribute("id",total); 
       document.body.appendChild(myDiv)

       $('#'+total).draggable().resizable();   
       document.getElementById(total).className += " drag";
}
```

Comment: It seems to work but if you were to drag one of the elements above the other element and then resize it, the other elements will float up for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already accepted an answer, but you COULD keep them generic and sort them with an array.

```
var total = 0;
var arr = new Array();
function add() {
    $('body').append('<div class="drag"></div>')
    arr.push($('.drag').eq(total));
    arr[total].draggable().resizable();
    total++;
}

add();
add();
add();
```